# What is the 'safe region' for iPhone X (in pixels) that factors the top notch and bottom bar?

Tags: ios, iphone-x

I have read the [Human Interface Guidelines for iPhone X](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/iphone-x/) and it doesn't specifically state the 'safe region' (area which caters for both top notch and bottom bar on the iPhone X). I would like to know the pixel dimensions of this region, including the dimensions removed from the top and bottom.

Answer (score 63):

**In Portrait**

- Top: 44pt
- Bottom: 34pt
- Left/Right: 0pt

**In Landscape**

- Top: 0pt
- Bottom: 21pt
- Left/Right: 44pt

[image]

[image]

Comment: Actually, it is 21pt on the bottom in Landscape, not 24pt

Comment: is this constant value in every device with a notch?

Comment: Nope, you should either use`safeAreaInsets` (prop from `UIViewController`) if you are coding an iOS or any lib that can help with that (for react-native/web https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context)

Answer (score 19):

By printing the safe area insets of the current window with the following code, you can get the point dimensions of the top and bottom safe area.

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets
    // ...
}
```

In portrait, the top area is **44 points** long and the bottom area is **34 points** in length.

Since iPhone X has a **@3x** resolution, the top area is **132 pixels** long and the bottom area is **102 pixels** in length.

Comment: How do you know in pixels that is 44? When I call to safeareainsets.top it gives me 88

Comment: @PabloMartinez https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46376860/what-is-the-safe-region-for-iphone-x-in-pixels-that-factors-the-top-notch-an/46377355#comment79770787_46377367

Answer (score 9):

Xcode 9 introduced safe-area layout guides into the interface builder. You can turn them on by going into your storyboard's file inspector and [ticking the checkbox labelled "Use Safe Area Layout Guides"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPYnw.png)

From there whenever you add constraints to your root view, you get the option of constraining it to the safe area instead. [In this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRMo6.png), the view in orange is constrained to the edges of the safe area while the view in blue is constrained to the edges of the superview.

- Orange view's frame: (0.0, 44.0, 375.0, 734.0)
- Blue view's frame: (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 812.0)

From there we can calculate that 44 points were used for the top safe area while 34 points were used for the bottom area.

Comment: How do you know in pixels that is 44? When I call to safeareainsets.top it gives me 88

Comment: @PabloMartinez the reason you are getting 88 pixels is because you have a navigation bar in your UI. The safe area layout guide is guaranteed to not be unobstructed by any other UI element such as a navigation bar or a tab bar. For more info, check out [Auto Layout Techniques in Interface Builder](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/412/) from this year's WWDC.

Comment: Do you have similar picture for landscape mode?

Comment: Ok so where is the status bar in this mode supposed to be?

Comment: @DeepakSharma from what I can see on the simulator, it's not shown at all when you're in landscape mode.

Comment: So iPhoneX screen is 1125x2436. The blue represents this and is 375x812. This is exactly 1/3 of the full resolution. Therefore 44x3 = 132 pixels from the top and the safe area is 375x734 x3 = 1125x2202. (This is for portrait).

Comment: You've said 44 pixels for the top and 34 pixels for the bottom. You probably mean points, not pixels?

Comment: @chichilatte you're absolutely right. I've edited the answer accordingly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from `safeAreaInsets` property of a view in a `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call the singleton `UIApplication`, can get them also from your view layout.

`self.view.safeAreaInstes.` (top,bottom,left.right)